# How can I upload my script.sql file and my database file to GoDaddy via Plesk?

Tags: sql-server, import, ssms, database-restore, plesk-onyx

I need help uploading my database to GoDaddy via Plesk.

I created a database with the name "ph20800551931_FlixForFams" in the Plesk Databases panel (locally, the original name of my database is "Flix4FamsData").

I want to upload/import the data as well as the script.sql file that I generated for re-creating the database on their server.

I followed the steps [here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/move-my-microsoft-sql-server-database-to-plesk-19838), but was unable to make a connection. This is what I entered in the Connect to Server dialog in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

...but got this err msg:

[image]

I also tried first uploading my database backup file via the Files tab in Plesk, but got an err msg that the file was too large, and to ftp it - but it doesn't provide me with the information I would need in order to do that using FileZilla, namely the Host, Username, Password, and Port.

By the way, for good (or bad) measure, I also tried the steps [here](https://www.fastwebhost.in/blog/upload-ms-sql-database-to-plesk-hosting/); it shows an "Import Dump" icon on the plesk Databases tab, but I do not have such:

[image]

So what steps do I need to take to upload my script.sql file to the Databases panel, and what are the  Host, Username, Password, and Port to use in ftp'ing my database file, and then getting it included in my Plesk Databases panel?

### UPDATE

I was able to get the database backup file (.bak) uploaded to the Files area after zipping it (.zip file 1/6th the size of the original):

[image]

And the database and its tables do exist, but they are empty:

[image]

So the question remains: how can I get get the database file (in the Files area) into the tables? Where do I need to move the zipped .bak file (and extract it) so that it will be found or I can access it from either the Plesk "My Little Admin" or from SSMS, or...? It kind of boggles my mind that there are so many hoops I have to jump through.

Comment: Usually these information is included in registration email.

Comment: Using SSMS, try connecting to the database's IP but without the port number. They say you don't need to for MySQL - maybe it applies to MSSQL too? https://au.godaddy.com/help/view-my-database-details-in-plesk-hosting-16022

Comment: Please just upload full .bak file to them and then ask them to restore your database. It will fix your problem.

Comment: @TheGunners: I tried to upload it, but got a message that the file was too large and to use ftp, but it didn't say what credentials I needed to use (which I mention at the end of my message above)

Comment: @seanb: Thanks, leaving off the port number worked. Now there are other issues, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64503483/would-removing-optimize-for-sequential-key-solve-the-failure-of-my-script-sql

Comment: @DipenShah: One would think so, but no, I had to search all over for instructions on what to do.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Try to zip it first and then upload it again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot restore database from your own `.bak` file due to [security concerns](https://ca.godaddy.com/community/GoDaddy-Web-Hosting/How-to-restore-a-ms-sql-database-from-local-computer-to-godaddy/td-p/53096).

That being said you can create `.SQL` file with your table and data, zip it, and restore using **Import Database Dump**.

**[Creating .sql script file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-and-publish-scripts-wizard?view=sql-server-2016)**

Although I do not have save SSMS as you are steps should be pretty similar.

1. Open Sql Server Management Studio
2. **Right click** on you database on the **Object Explorer** panel
3. **Click** on **Tasks > Generate Scripts** menu item
4. Follow the steps in the wizard and select **Script entire database and all database objects**
5. Finish wizard and modify **.sql file to change database name to same name that your GoDaddy database have**
6. Zip .sql file

**[Importing Database Dump](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/restore-my-database-in-plesk-hosting-19973)**

1. Go to your GoDaddy product page.
2. Click Plesk Admin.
3. In the left-hand menu click **Databases**.
4. Click **Import Dump**.
5. The Import Database Dump window will open.
6. Select Upload and click Browse to choose a ZIP archive on your computer. Or, select Import to choose a file from the directory.
7. Check Recreate the database, and then click OK.

Comment: Thanks; I think this would work if I had access to the "Import" button, but I don't. Somebody on the Plesk forum said that was for admin accounts. I have a "Subscriber" account, so I don't see the Import button - it's not exposed to me. I'll try your steps, though, to see what happens. It certainly looks like "just what the non-doctor ordered" - thanks again, Dipen!

Comment: I guess in that case you only option would be to run the same script file on database instance you connect to from SQL management studio.

Comment: After working through the first section (I just wanted to see to which point I could get), the .sql file is only 17KB, so no need to zip it. It just contains a description of the database, not data itself.

Comment: There should be a configuration dialog which would allow your to select what do you want to include in script file. Check step 5 here, unfortunately I couldn't paste screenshot here:
https://dzone.com/articles/generate-database-scripts-with-data-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks again, Dipen; I did select the "Script entire database and all database objects" checkbox...